# What is the command for sectioning a data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Sorry, I googled and couldn't find an answer, so I post the question here, sorry to bother the others.

My question is how to section out a data range using matlab, which command should I use?

I mean, given a data/time series, I wanna use my mouse to select the range for further investigation.

Thanks a lot!

Daniel Wei

Comment: What do you mean by "use my mouse to select the range"?

Comment: Please see page 2-31 in this link, thanks, www.ctr.unican.es/asignaturas/instrumentacion_5_IT/curvefit.pdf

Comment: You're seriously asking for help by requesting that the potential answerers read 30 pages of some random instruction manual?

Comment: Not just some random manual; the link is to a copy of the manual for Curve Fitting Toolbox, and to the page that kind of answers the OP's question.

And by the way, that manual's copyright is owned by MathWorks, and you're not allowed to redistribute it on your own website.

Comment: I feel surprised that stackoverflow has such a strict game rule, even though I am seriously asking the help. (1) it is not my website, I just googled it. (2) It is a curvefitting toolbox, but there is no direct answer in that file showing which command I should use. (3) I apologize, but I also want to say, that even though I am able to find a answer by myself in 20 minutes, but I failed to see why that looking for a QUICK answer from those EXPERIENCED users is a big fault here. I am a little frustrated by what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for [data brushing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/data_analysis/brh7_p3-1.html) (see also [this part of the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/bq45say-1.html#bril77l) and [this video](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/matlab/linked-plots-and-data-brushing.html)).

Comment: Thank you, Sir. But it is not what I am looking for, I want use mouse to stylishly set the left bound, and right bound of a target data, that is to set the starting time line and ending time line of a time history of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like [ginput](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html)? Just a guess...